# ImageView expands when displaying an image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to make a layout with 10 equal height rows, each row containing an ImageView and a TextView.    When I put an image into the ImageView, I would like it scaled to retain the same aspect and fit inside the ImageView, not changing the ImageView size or the height of the containing TableRow.

The problem I have is that when I load an image into the ImageView, the ImageView seems to expand, and it also changes the height of the TableRow (?)  I've been looking at this for a while, but can't seem to get it to work.   It's possible I have missed one of the details of how Android layout or an ImageView works (?)

I've created a smaller example from my code which exhibits the problem.   I've also set the background color on the ImageView so it is easier to see it change size.

Below are my layout files and code (apologies for the formatting, I have also put the complete Eclipse project at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28937795/ImageRowSample.zip)

Any help would be appreciated.  =)

```
MAIN.XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>



<TableRow style="@style/SlashRowStyle">
    <ImageView style="@style/SlashViewStyle" />
    <TextView  style="@style/NumberViewStyle" android:text="0" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow style="@style/SlashRowStyle">
    <ImageView style="@style/SlashViewStyle" />
    <TextView  style="@style/NumberViewStyle" android:text="1" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow style="@style/SlashRowStyle">
    <!-- I'm setting the background of this ImageView 
                 so it's easier to see it change size -->
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image2" style="@style/SlashViewStyle" 
               android:background="#FF0000"/>
    <TextView  style="@style/NumberViewStyle" android:text="2" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow style="@style/SlashRowStyle">
    <ImageView style="@style/SlashViewStyle" />
    <TextView  style="@style/NumberViewStyle" android:text="3" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow style="@style/SlashRowStyle">
    <ImageView style="@style/SlashViewStyle" />
    <TextView  style="@style/NumberViewStyle" android:text="4" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow style="@style/SlashRowStyle">
    <ImageView style="@style/SlashViewStyle" />
    <TextView  style="@style/NumberViewStyle" android:text="5" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow style="@style/SlashRowStyle">
    <ImageView style="@style/SlashViewStyle" />
    <TextView  style="@style/NumberViewStyle" android:text="6" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow style="@style/SlashRowStyle">
    <ImageView style="@style/SlashViewStyle" />
    <TextView  style="@style/NumberViewStyle" android:text="7" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow style="@style/SlashRowStyle">
    <ImageView style="@style/SlashViewStyle" />
    <TextView  style="@style/NumberViewStyle" android:text="8" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow style="@style/SlashRowStyle">
    <ImageView  style="@style/SlashViewStyle" />
    <TextView  style="@style/NumberViewStyle" android:text="9" />
</TableRow>


<LinearLayout style="@style/ButtonBarStyle" >
    <Button android:text="Add Image" android:onClick="onClickedAddImage" 
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button android:text="Clear Image" android:onClick="onClickedClearImage"  
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

.

```
STYLES.XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="SlashRowStyle" >
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>

<style name="SlashViewStyle" >
    <!--  I want scaling so it fits in the Imageview with the same aspect. 
          I tried both fitCenter and centerInside   -->
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitCenter</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">40</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>       
</style>

<style name="NumberViewStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">60</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>       

    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#0000FF</item>
</style>


<style name="ButtonBarStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:background">#404040</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dip</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

.

```
IMAGEROWSAMPLEACTIVITY.JAVA

public class ImageRowSampleActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView _iv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    _iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
}



public void onClickedAddImage(View v) {
    _iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
}



public void onClickedClearImage(View v) {
    //_iv.setImageResource(0);      //Tried this also
    _iv.setImageDrawable(null);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at it some more I finally stumbled onto the answer.

The problem is the TableRows in the TableLayout.   The Android SDK TableLayout doc says that

> The children of a TableLayout cannot specify the layout_width attribute. Width is always
>   MATCH_PARENT. However, the layout_height attribute can be defined by a child; default value
>   is WRAP_CONTENT. If the child is a TableRow, then the height is always WRAP_CONTENT.

The TableRow doc also says

> The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height 
>   attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively 
>   MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.

So, yeah, the problem was the TableRows always ignoring my settings and making their  heights WRAP_CONTENT, then also forcing the ImageView's height to be WRAP_CONTENT.  When I converted the TableLayout and TableRows to LinearLayouts with the correct orientations, everything worked as I originally expected...

Comment: I ran into similar situation. Before coverting everything into linear layouts as you suggested, just wanted to know, is there anything that we can fix in tablelayout itself?